# Can I use FFTW3 with multi-threads on windows?

Tags: windows, fftw

I install "fftw3.h" on the windows system to execute my ".cu".

```
#include "fftw3.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "libfftw3-3.lib")
```

I can use most functions of FFTW3 in my codes. However, when "***fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int)***" or "***fftw_init_threads()***" are executed, there is an error code **code=3221225785**.

How can I use FFTW3 with multi-threads on windows? Whether the windows version of FFTW3 supports such operations?

Answer (score 0):

1- .cu extension is for cuda style programming and almost is GPU based. You use cpu  version of fftw...

2- Firstly prepare the Threads, after that  create the Plan such as  the follow (note the clean up ):

```
fftw_init_threads();//m
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(24);//m

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(NFFT, SubFrame.data(), ...

fftw_execute(plan);

fftw_cleanup_threads();//m

fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
```